# $.Ajax send with progress bar using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

Hi folks
I use $.ajax functionality to send data to server and with this method I removed most of postback pages it works but I need some progress bar to show visitors there are some progress now it shows nothing after some second it shows result but i think a message or small picture is need in my web site. How I can implement it with simple jquery code ? something popup and shows the page is in the progress.

And also I need to add some other jquery to prevent other click during the progress is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$("elemnt").click(function(){
    $("loader-img").show();

    $.ajax({
        url : "your url",
        complete: function(){
            $("loader-img").hide();
        }
    });    
});
```

The loader image can be an page blocking div, to block the user from doing anything with a image at the center of the viewport.

Here the complete event is used since this event is called in case of a successful/failed ajax request.

EDITED
You can do something like

```
<style type="text/css">
    .blocker{
        z-index: 99999;
        opacity: .5;
        height: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lightgrey;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .blocker .img{
        position: fixed;
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="blocker" style="display: none">
        <div class="img">img</div>
    </div>
    .............
    .............
    .............
```

Then In Script

```
function showBlocker(){
    $(".blocker .img").css({
        top: $(window).height() / 2,
        left: $(window).width() / 2
    });
    $(".blocker").show().css({
        height: $(document).height()
    });
}
```

Then call the `showBlocker()` method to show the blocker.

You can tweak the answer to fit into your need. This is just a sample how it can be achieved

Comment: blocking div with the absolute position must be center of the page to prevent click is that your mean ?

Answer (score 1):

You can show a loading image before the AJAX call starts and then hide it in the callback function.

Something like

```
// handler for ajax trigger
$("#yourelement").click(function(){
    // your loading image object
    $("#yourimage").show();
    $.ajax({
       url: 'ajax/test.html',
       success: function(data) {
         $("#yourimage").hide();
       }
    });
});
```